# Access a third party's iframe's redux store

Tags: redux, iframe, react-redux

As part of a project I am working on, I have integrated an iframe from a 3rd party service. This iframe sends a message when its task is completed, but the message has no data in it, just a success message. In the console, the iframe is constantly logging its redux state which has a lot of good information that I want. I can also see this information using redux developer tools. Is there any way to access the redux state of this third party app from within my react/redux app? I can't find it stored anywhere on the window or anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. It would be a security concern, otherwise.

The iframe would need some worker that would actively send information to your app, that would accept that work, so both instances can communicate with each other.